# Intellij - modified vs staged files[Local changes view]

Tags: git, intellij-idea

I use the currently latest Intellij version - `IntelliJ IDEA 2023.2.5 (Ultimate Edition)`

I am trying to figure out why I can not see the difference in the Local Changes tab, under Git when some files have been modified(just changed but not added) and have been staged(changed and added for commit)

Example with `pom.xml` file that has been added for commit, and the rest two are just modified

Here is the IntelliJ Local Changes state - no difference(expect some color or icon)

[image: IntelliJ Local Changes]

Here is the GitBash state - a pretty obvious difference
[image: GitBash]

It is pretty uncomfortable as when I am working with many files some of them are added in different timeframe and I can not find a way to differentiate which have been added and which are still not and should be

Answer (score 0):

According to IntelliJ's documentation, [they *intentionally* combine Unstaged and Staged files](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/undo-changes.html#unstage-files) - but you can enable more sane settings by going **Version Control > Git > Enable staging area**

> By default, [IntelliJ IDEA uses the changelists concept](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/managing-changelists.html) where modified files are staged automatically.
>
> If a file is already under version control, and you do not want to commit it, you can:
>
> - Remove it from the commit: do not select it in the Changes area of the Commit tool window.
> - Move it to another changelist.
>
> If you are more used to the staging concept, select the **Enable staging area** option in the **Version Control > Git** page of the **IDE settings**
>
> Also, by default IntelliJ IDEA suggests adding each newly created file under version control. You can change this behavior in **Settings > Version Control > Confirmation** using **When files are created* and **When files are deleted** settings respectively.

<sub>(NGL, I'd like to see `git` get first-class support for multiple active staging areas - I'm not an IntelliJ user so I don't know *how good* their implementation is, but I think it's a good idea to *not fight the system* and try to force `git` to behave like SVN/TFS/etc)</sub>

Comment: `By default, IntelliJ IDEA uses the changelists concept where modified files are staged automatically.` Looks like it combines them but does not show/mark which is just modified but not staged using `git add` and which changes are staged(git added). That's what I am searching for

Comment: @TsvetoslavTsvetkov, this is not possible with changelists. Changelists can be used to re-create this scenario by making changelists with different names, for an example:
1) Changelist to commit
2) Not to commit

And you can easily navigate between these two changelists and place your changes inside any of them. 

Additionally, it does not combine it, if you modify file it will automatically appear under changelist and it won't be staged until you commit it via interface. What could have happen in your case is that files were changed and you used git add on some of them.

Comment: @DinoLetic All of the files are staged(under version control). Yes, the files `pom.xml` that had been changed manually were added, while the rest of two that also have been changed I left them(no `git add` for them) just to show how using CLI I managed to see staged files which have been changes and git added and the one that are changed but not git added. The problem is that I can't find a way to do the same using `IntelliJ`, so I have to go back and forth between IntelliJ Git Tool and Git CLI